# How to run a Firebase Transaction using Kotlin Coroutines?

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to run a Firebase Transaction under a suspended function in Kotlin and i see no documentation about it.

I'm using

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.5.2'
```

for coroutines with firebase (eg: **setValue(*).await()** ) but there seems to be no await function for **runTransaction(*)**

```
override suspend fun modifyProductStock(
    product: ProductModel,
    valueToModify: Long,
    replace: Boolean
) {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        val restaurantId = authRepository.restaurantId.value ?: throw Exception("No restaurant!")

        val productId = product.id ?: throw Exception("No Product ID!")

        val reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("database/$restaurantId").child("products")

        if (replace) {
            reference.child(productId).child("stock").setValue(valueToModify).await()
        } else {
            reference.child(productId).child("stock")
                .runTransaction(object : Transaction.Handler {

                    override fun doTransaction(p0: MutableData): Transaction.Result {
                        //any operation
                        return Transaction.success(p0)
                    }

                    override fun onComplete(p0: DatabaseError?, p1: Boolean, p2: DataSnapshot?) {
                    }

                })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could wrap it in `suspendCoroutine`:

```
val result: DataSnapshot? = suspendCoroutine { c ->
    reference.child(productId).child("stock")
        .runTransaction(object : Transaction.Handler {
            override fun doTransaction(p0: MutableData): Transaction.Result {
                //any operation
                return Transaction.success(p0)
            }
    
            override fun onComplete(error: DatabaseError?, p1: Boolean, snapshot: DataSnapshot?) {
                c.resume(snapshot)
            }
        })
}
```

[suspendCoroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html)

> Obtains the current continuation instance inside suspend functions and suspends the currently running coroutine.
> In this function both Continuation.resume and Continuation.resumeWithException can be used either synchronously in the same stack-frame where the suspension function is run or asynchronously later in the same thread or from a different thread of execution.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the [Kotlin example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#kotlin+ktx_9) in the Firebase documentation on [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) uses the same callback style that you have, it seems indeed that there is no specific support for co-routines there.

It might be worth posting an issue on the [Android SDK repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk) to get it added, or hear why it wasn't added.